# Error trying to delete item in restserver codeigniter. I have this error: any idea?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I get the error:

> failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

Method to delete:

```
public function borrar_item_delete()
{
    $id = (int) $this->delete('id');

    // Validate the id.
    if ($id <= 0)
    {
        // Set the response and exit
        $this->response(NULL, REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST); // BAD_REQUEST (400) being the HTTP response code
    }

    $this->db->delete('pedido_fila', array('id' => $id));    

    $message = [
        'id' => $id,
        'message' => 'Deleted the resource'
    ];

    $this->set_response($message, REST_Controller::HTTP_NO_CONTENT); // NO_CONTENT (204) being the HTTP response code
}
```

Ajax request:

```
var id_order = 1;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.api.verdulero.com/index.php/api/Pedidos/borrar_item?id='+id_order, 
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function(){
            alert(id_order);
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        }
    });
```

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: Hello here is my code, I can figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You Cannot Delete using HTTP, you have to use the local file system to delete files.

This might help:

[Http write](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/file_write_php.htm)

[Memcache Delete](http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.delete.php)